# Android - how to change the background of linked text in Spannable String?

Tags: android, linked-list, textview, highlight, linkify

I have a textView which uses Linkifier along with SpannableString.
What I want is that when the user TOUCHES the linked text (like a hashtag or mention), the linked text (part of the whole TextView) will be highlighted (or the background of the linked text will change). But it seems like there is no way to get touchEvent for spannable. 
If you see the native twitter app, if you touch a link, you see the linked text will be highlighted. Is there a way to implement this feature? Any help is appreciated!